# List View inside SurfaceView android

Tags: android, listview, android-camera, surfaceview

Is it possible to add list view into surface view?

I mean like the camera application in Samsung Galaxy S4.

When the camera is open it shows list view of effect and shows you how the picture in the surface view will be with the effects. 
I'm trying to do my own, but I wonder how to show the effect on the picture in the surfaceview in real time.

I know I need to create my own surface view and handle the camera events myself, but how can I add list view effect in real time?

[Example for what I asked for](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=samsung%20galaxy%20s4%20camera&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=600&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=4itiVPzLAfC07QbfioDADQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=samsung%20galaxy%20s4%20camera%20effects&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=DQDOWs61iXaFmM%253A%3BzHVORy0PDPaiyM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.gadgetguy.com.au%252Fcms%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252Fsamung-galaxy-s4-screenshot-camera-03.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.gadgetguy.com.au%252Fproduct%252Fsamsung-galaxy-s4-gt-i9505%252Fsamung-galaxy-s4-screenshot-camera-03%252F%3B900%3B506)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you need to add ListView inside *SurfaceView*.
Android Framework allows you to use `FrameLayout` container. I think you can try following layout:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <SurfaceView/>
   <ListView/>
</FrameLayoout>
```

Then In your code your can control ListView visibility, i.e. when you need to display settings list, set `ListView` visibility to `VISIBLE`.

Comment: and there is any restricts? I mean I have 3 tabs - each one is a fragment, and in one of the tabs I want to open the camera when the user press on it. so the user will see what he wants to capture but will also will see the effects in list view

Comment: @Elior sorry, I don't get your question. Maybe you can draw schematic layout of your app.